# Why does this question appear to be acceptable?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-question, question-quality

The question in question is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18270053/838807).

Personally I think the question is not suitable, yet many others appears to be happy with it.

The reasons I don't find it suitable are as follows:

1. No code is shown for either algorithm eliminating any comparative answers
2. "Efficient" is a vague term, and is not clarified within the question
3. It's a broad subject (I could see a whole book on this topic)
4. Everyone has their own opinions (as indicated by comments/questions)

So convince me, why is the question acceptable?

On a side note, which may not be the case with this question, I feel some people upvote questions just because they find them interesting, regardless of the quality.

**EDIT**: Just to point out, although this meta post does reference a specific question, I am asking about the acceptability of questions like this in general. I have not brought this up just to get some attention on the question I have linked, I want to know peoples opinion on whether or not this type of question is acceptable, and why.

Comment: Who said it is? It was asked 45 minutes ago and has 2 close votes for "Too Broad" at the moment.

Comment: @ColeJohnson: It only had one vote when I posted this (and it was mine), perhaps this meta post has prompted some more intelligent reviewing of the question

Comment: 45 minutes is a short time though.

Comment: @ColeJohnson: Maybe, but considering how many questions get asked these days, and that it has multiple upvotes with an accepted answer, I can't see it getting many reviews further down the line

Comment: Now **that** reasoning for asking is acceptable!

Comment: The answer that question received shows that there's definitely something interesting and on topic struggling to get out, and _great answers_ are a definite indicator that the question does or at leas could have merit. If put on hold, I'm sure the question could be narrowed a bit to be a better fit, it looks like the author just got a little lost in thought while asking.

Comment: @TimPost: I see what you are saying, but in this example, there are multiple answers with conflicting opinions which indicates that the question is primarily opinion based. I would like to see you, or another, try and convert that into a more specific acceptable question

Comment: @musefan I just did (try).

Answer (score 6):

> No code is shown for either algorithm eliminating any comparative answers

Code would be completely irrelevant for this question.

> "Efficient" is a vague term, and is not clarified within the question

The asker is asking about the meaning of “efficient”. Of course he can't clarify what it means, that's the whole point of the question.

> It's a broad subject (I could see a whole book on this topic)

Agreed.

> Everyone has their own opinions (as indicated by comments/questions)

No. Different people have different understandings of the question, which is not the same thing. This is largely a consequence of the question being too broad.

There are definitely interesting things to be said on the topic. There's quite a bit I could add that isn't covered in the existing answers. That's again unsurprising given the breadth of the question.

I hesitate to vote to reopen because I don't see a way to make the question less broad. On the other hand, I don't think the question is so broad as to be unanswerable.

I wonder if the question would fare better on [Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/). It isn't off-topic on Stack Overflow, but it does grate with the “debug-my-code only” part of the SO community.

I can't comment on the “acceptability of questions like this in general” because I have no idea what you mean by “questions like this”.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct - in its current form, the question is not suitable for Stack Overflow.

People often up-vote questions that are not suitable for the SE site in question. I would prefer that they didn't, but it doesn't really hurt anybody - votes are not the primary method through which off-topic questions are handled.

At the time of writing, the question <strike>now has three close votes</strike> is now on hold. It looks like the community is doing its job, as usual. The question will eventually be closed and order restored to the universe. Once an off-topic question has been flagged (or the first vote received), it will normally be closed eventually thanks to the closure and flag review queues. Sometimes it just takes a while, depending upon how many 3k+ users are browswing.

Comment: So do you agree that this question should be closed? And although votes do not indicate if they are off topic, they must have a relation to peoples acceptance of the question? And unfortunately, we are at a loss to know if the community is doing it's job with the close votes, or if my creation of this post has caused the question to be reviewed and therefore voted on

Comment: @musefan Yes, the question should be closed. In fact I delivered the coup de grâce. People vote for questions for a wide range of reasons and it's not a guaranteed indicator of whether the question belongs on the site.

Comment: The Meta effect, we call it. *All* of those votes came from people looking at this Meta question. It would have taken longer if it weren't brought up here. But that doesn't justify bringing up every off-topic question posted within the last hour that isn't closed.

Comment: @CodyGray: The question I linked is just an example to give background to my discussion. I never have, or never will make a meta post saying "please review and close this question". Normally I would register my vote and move on, but because this question seemed to get so much approval (upvotes and answers) I thought I would seek clarification on these type of questions. I don't want to go around close-voting things that are actually deemed acceptable